# php drop down menu to delete from database

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to delete a news event from the database by selecting the news event from a drop down menu. When the user selects the news title and presses the submit button the news item should be deleted from the relevant table. I cannot get this to work correctly no matter what i try. Sorry I am new to PHP.
Can someone help please? here is the drop down menu:

```
    $sql="SELECT newstitle FROM $tbl_name";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    ?>

    <select name="select1">
    <?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['newstitle'];?>"> <?php echo $row['newstitle'];?>         </option>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </select>


    <td><center><input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete"></center></td>
```

I have also this code to delete from the database when the button is pressed?

```
    $delete=$_POST['delete'];
    $delete = mysql_real_escape_string($delete);

    mysql_query ("DELETE FROM $tbl_name WHERE newstitle='$delete'") or die ("Error- news has not been deleted");
        echo "News has been deleted";
        header("Location: newsdeleted.php");
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: In addition to what @Truth said, you are currently open to some severe SQL injection, and you **will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  If you learn to properly use prepared statements, this will no longer be an issue for you.  Also, you cannot use a relative path in a `Location:` header.  While it will work most of the time, the RFCs say you can't use it.  Finally, don't use `<center>` tags.  They've been dead for quite some time now.  Use CSS to style your page.

Answer (score 0):

- `$tbl_name` is not set on your delete script.
- Please read up about SQL Injection, filter your input, escape your query
- You should use [PHP PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) rather than old mysql funcs
- Your header line won't work unless you are buffering as you have already output to stdout.
- Your select input is called `select1` not `delete`

Answer (score 0):

```
// Your check for the "delete" submit value goes here
// Submit name and value are both 'delete'
if (isset($_POST['delete']) && $_POST['delete'] == 'delete') {
  // This is the value passed from the form (use select element's name)
  $selected_newstitle = $_POST['select1'];
  ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry I Am not sure where you mean to insert this, do i put it in above the mysql_query?